# save the image to the gallery in android

Tags: android

How can i save the image that the camera take into the gallery? i have this code but doesn't save the image

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
// Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, /* prefix */
                ".jpg", /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
        );

// Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

and almost use thise one

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

but doesn't have a positive result, in my manifest i use this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

Comment: did you add runtime permission

Comment: the only permission that appears is the one of if i want to give permission to use the camera

Comment: in which os version you are running your application

Comment: in the 6.0 and in the 7.1

Comment: then you need to ask runtime permission for storing the image in internal storage my friend [read from docs about runtime permsiion](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Just to make sure that runtime permissions is causing the problem, go to `Settings->Apps->Your_app->Permissions->enable the storage permission` and then check your application once more. check if the image is saved or not..Please remember that you'll have to give runtime permissions, if you are targeting for Android 6.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

From android version M and above, Runtime permission is required for any dangerous permission - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

```
public void checkPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (!(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (!(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Storage Permission not granted");   
    } else {
        // Permission granted - resume
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with requestCode?

Comment: You should look at the documnetation here for the API - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[], int)