# MediaPlayer not playing files from Android Emulator's SD Card

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer

I've been working on an MP3 player in Android Studio 2.3.3, but I haven't been able to make the MediaPlayer class work. I've uploaded some MP3 files on my virtual Android device (Android 7.0), but I cannot set a correct path to any of them. What I do is pretty simple:

```
try{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/03. Bloom.mp3"));
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception ex){}
```

But it doesn't want to work. I've tried also

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/03. Bloom.mp3"));
```

Neither of those options work. I'm sure the song is in this folder [(proof pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp2h5.png).

I would really appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: what is the error? Did you specify External storage permission?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/03. Bloom.mp3 (Permission denied)
It's the error I get. It must then have something to do with storage permission. What do I do?

Comment: Please refer to the answer here for specifying runtime permissions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762797/1099156